# gulp command giving error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp

I am trying to run "gulp" command in my react application. But i am getting error saying

```
D:\te-client-2>gulp
[23:15:25] Requiring external module babel-register
D:\tessact-client-2\gulpfile.babel.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import gulp from 'gulp';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at loader (D:\te-client-2\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\te-client-2\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
```

What is the reason and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

My project was missing .babelrc file. I just added the file and added the below lines of code to it

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0", "react" ]
}
```